# finding frequencies using characteristic equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, characteristic-polynomial

i am trying to figure out how to use the solutions of characteristic equations to find the frequencies of their related oscillators.

my first differential equation is this:

$y''[t] + 4 \pi \cdot y[t] = 0$

and the solutions to its characteristic equation are:

$z = +/-2\pi \cdot i$

i also have another one:

$20.1 \cdot y[t] + 5.7 \cdot y'[t] + y''[t] = 0$

its solutions to its characteristic equation are:

$-2.85 +/- 3.46085 \cdot i$

i have searched a lot online but i can't find any straightforward explanations for how to approach these problems. any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you want "$4\pi^2$" in your first differential equation or did you want "$\pm 2 \sqrt{\pi} \, \mathrm{i}$" (`$\pm 2 \sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{i}$`) as the solution of its characteristic equation?

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward application of the method of the [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)) for solving linear, constant coefficient, ordinary differential equations.  Having substituted $y = \mathrm{e}^{rt}$ into the equation and factoring out and cancelling the never zero $\mathrm{e}^{rt}$ factor, what remains is the characteristic polynomial.  It's roots are the choices of $r$ that make the substitution work.  So the solutions are $y(t) = \mathrm{e}^{r_1 t}$ and $y(t) = \mathrm{e}^{r_2 t}$.  Now use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to see that the real part of $r$ tells you about the amplitude (increasing with time if $\Re r > 0$ and decreasing with time if $\Re r < 0$) and the imaginary part tells you the frequency of oscillation, that frequency being $\frac{2\pi}{\Im r}$.

(Notation: $\Re$ is the real part of a complex number and $\Im$ is the imaginary part.  So $\Re(1+2\mathrm{i}) = 1$ and $\Im(1+2 \mathrm{i}) = 2$.)

For your second example:
\begin{align*}
y''(t) + \frac{57}{10} y'(t) + \frac{201}{10} y(t) &= 0  \\
    y(t) &= \mathrm{e}^{rt}  \\
    y'(t) &= r \mathrm{e}^{rt}  \\
    y''(t) &= r^2 \mathrm{e}^{rt}  \\
r^2 \mathrm{e}^{rt} + \frac{57}{10} r \mathrm{e}^{rt} + \frac{201}{10} \mathrm{e}^{rt} &= 0  \\
(r^2 + \frac{57}{10} r + \frac{201}{10}) \mathrm{e}^{rt} &= 0  \\
r^2 + \frac{57}{10} r + \frac{201}{10} &= 0  \\
r &= \frac{1}{20}(-57 \pm \mathrm{i}\,\sqrt{4791})  \\
y_1(t) &= \mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{20}(-57 + \mathrm{i}\,\sqrt{4791})t}  \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-57}{20}t} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\sqrt{4791}}{20}\mathrm{i}t}   \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-57}{20}t} \left( \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{4791}}{20}t \right) + \mathrm{i} \sin \left( \frac{\sqrt{4791}}{20}t \right) \right) \text{and}  \\
y_2(t) &= \mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{20}(-57 - \mathrm{i}\,\sqrt{4791})}  \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-57}{20}t} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-\sqrt{4791}}{20}\mathrm{i}t}   \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-57}{20}t} \left( \cos \left(\frac{-\sqrt{4791}}{20}t \right) + \mathrm{i} \sin \left( \frac{-\sqrt{4791}}{20}t \right) \right)
\end{align*}

Of course, the frequency of $\cos(at)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{a}$ and similarly for sine, obtaining the frequency
$$  \frac{2\pi}{\frac{\sqrt{4791}}{20}} = 1.815{\dots}  $$
with units that are the reciprocal of the units of $t$ (Hertz if $t$ is in seconds).